# Playing audio/video in QNX Qt

Tags: c++, qt, audio, video, qnx

I am using Qt 5.3.1 for QNX 6.6.0 + Apps and Media 1.1. I try to play audio/video from my HMI app. However, I get an error message saying "checkForDrmPermission: Unable to open bar-descriptor.xml".

After some googling, I found the open source code which matches here:

https://fossies.org/linux/misc/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.0.tar.gz/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.0/qtmultimedia/src/plugins/qnx/mediaplayer/mmrendererutil.cpp

Do I have to create bar-descriptor.xml and install my app with .bar file in order to be able to play audio/video?